# Set up a Bitcoin full node: static or dynamic IP address?

Tags: full-node, attack

I am trying to set up a new Bitcoin full node and my institution ISP is trying hard to not give me a static IP address for this purpose. I guess because of the concern that the node will be DDoSed, port scanned, etc.
My questions are:

1. How frequently a full node with static IP get DDoSed?
2. Is there any strong reason for favoring static IP address over dynamic IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How frequently a full node with static IP get DDoSed?

It is unlikely that data is available on this.

> Is there any strong reason for favoring static IP address over dynamic IP address?

It would simplify external service connections, but there is no real reason you can't run a full node on a dynamic IP. It would simply require some additional work to set up a dynamic dns service, if you do need a dns pointer to the node.

Answer (score 2):

> How frequently a full node with static IP get DDoSed?

It depends on who owns the full node, and whether the owner of a full node is known. A full node by itself is unlikely to be DDoS'd since there is little point in attacking any random node. However, if the node is owned by, say, an exchange and it is known that the node is owned by the exchange, it might be DDoS'd as attacking that node may result in some gain for the attacker. But in general, full nodes don't get DDoS'd because there's no point.

> Is there any strong reason for favoring static IP address over dynamic IP address?

Connections that peers make to you are based upon the IP address. They remember the IP addresses of other nodes and try to reconnect to them later if they go offline. With a static IP address, it is more likely that your node will get connections because it will have been at the same IP address for a while and nodes have remembered it. Static IP has no effect on your outbound connections (which, to your node, are the most important, not the inbound ones).